# Deprecated Methods in the Thread Class for Android Programming

Tags: java, android, thread-safety

I was going over the Android API reference documents and came to know that some methods in the Thread class were deprecated for various reasons. Here are some excerpts:

---

public final void suspend ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 1.
May cause deadlocks.

---

public final void resume ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 1.
Used with deprecated method suspend()

---

public final synchronized void stop (Throwable throwable)

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 1.
because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

---

public final void stop ()

Added in API level 1
This method was deprecated in API level 1.
because stopping a thread in this manner is unsafe and can leave your application and the VM in an unpredictable state.

Requests the receiver Thread to stop and throw ThreadDeath. The Thread is resumed if it was suspended and awakened if it was sleeping, so that it can proceed to throw ThreadDeath.

---

The Thread class is also part of the Java standard API and, from my Java programming background, I previously came across those methods but Sun never put any such notice of deprecation in the standard Java API.

Should pure Java programs (free of the Android environment) ignore those warnings and continue to use the methods? Thanks.

Comment: Those methods are deprecated as per the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), in the Standard Java API as well, because some of them are **deadlock-prone**.

Comment: Agreed. Those have been deprecated in standard Java for well over a decade.

Comment: Wow, time to brush up myself.... But it would help if Oracle could altogether remove those methods.

Comment: @MohammadAliAsgar They were deprecated as of JDK 1.1! More about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods are deprecated as they can cause dead-locks and sometimes cause unexpected behavior.

See [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.in/2008/07/why-stop-suspend-resume-of-thread-are.html) for detailed explaination of the different issues